# PHP Change Image Location

Tags: php, image, content-management-system

I was using an old content management system, that uses CKEditor with CKFinder, that allows you to upload images to the server, however it puts in the full URL into the content box, and later i save it to the database.

I have recently rebuilt my content management system and again using CKEditor with CKFinder. I am currently in the process of moving the database and rearranging the data. But i have noticed that the URL for these images would be wrong.

So my question is, is it possible to search and replace the URL, and could be multiple times per string? Also there is a random hash key in the middle, which i am not too sure how to get around, which is why i am asking this question.

The URL would be (unedited)

```
http://www.oldwebsite.com/aknsnd8123nakndkna/upload/images/image.jpg
```

I would like to extract the url and change its path to:

```
http://www.newwebsite.com/images/uploaded/image.jpg
```

I am not to sure how i would get the start and end, whilst skipping the middle part. Or is it possible to just get the image.jpg at the end, and i'll put in the new path at the beginning.

I only have 2 lines of code so far, but to bare in mind that it is HTML.

```
$content = '<h1>'.$page['Page_Title'].'</h1>';
$content .= $page['Page_Content'];
```

This is what `$page['Page_Content']` returns:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <img alt="" src="http://www.oldwebsite.com/aknsnd8123nakndkna/upload/images/image.jpg" style="width: 700px; height: 493px;" />
</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    The Sports Stadium is an impressive addition to any event, catering for several sports keeping children entertained for hours.
</p>
```

Comment: You haven't provided much information... Do you want to write a migration script to alter data in some kind of database or storage system?

Comment: I am writing the migration script at the moment, i am fetching the data from the old database, rearranging it, then inserting it, into the new database. What i am asking help with is during the rearranging part, before i send it to the new database.

Comment: Since everything else seem to be clear... You need to find a PHP library to connect to your database (PDO has drivers for several engines), use DOMDocument or a similar parser to extract links from HTML and compose a regular expression to process the actual replacements.

Comment: I tried what you said with DOMDocument, see my answer is that what you had in mind? Thank you for the the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is your table structure. You can run a mysql query like the below on your old database to update the paths. If this does not help you, post your table structure and I will happy to update my answer.

```
sql=" UPDATE page SET page_content = REPLACE(page_content, 'http://www.oldwebsite.com/aknsnd8123nakndkna/upload/images/', 'http://www.newwebsite.com/images/uploaded/')";
```

Hope this help.

Comment: The column `Page_Content` contains HTML - as per my edited question. Would that work? even if the row contains HTML?

Comment: @Sickaaron, what is the name of ur table, I presume 'page'. If so I have updated the query. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it! Thanks to Álvaro González for the suggestion!

```
    $content = '<h1>'.$page['Page_Title'].'</h1>';
    $content .= $page['Page_Content'];  
    $html = new DOMDocument(); 
    $html->loadHTML($content);  
    foreach ($html->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image) {
        $img = array_reverse(explode('/', $image->getAttribute('src')));
        $image->setAttribute('src', $website.'/images/uploaded/'.$img[0]);
    }
    $content = $html->saveHTML();
```